# Messages aren't built

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've downloaded a ROS package and I would like to use its messages in my program, however, for some weird reason the messages aren't built and thus I get an error.

My package.xml has this:

```
<exec_depend>nerian_stereo</exec_depend>
```

my CMakeLists.txt has this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  message_runtime
  std_msgs
  nerian_stereo
)
```

and my code file has this:

```
from nerian_stereo import * 
self.camera_info = rospy.Subscriber("/nerian_stereo/stereo_camera_info", StereoCameraInfo ,self.stereo_camera_cb)
```

however I still get this annoying error of:

```
NameError: global name 'StereoCameraInfo' is not defined
```

What's wrong? I also observed my `catkin_make` and I see that this package is not built at all, the output does not show its name. Is there yet another file which needs to be edited?

EDIT: Here is the message: http://docs.ros.org/api/nerian_stereo/html/msg/StereoCameraInfo.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315953/messages-aren%27t-built/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-02-18**:
Can you locate your package with `rospack find` ?

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-18**:
Yes, it returns `/opt/ros/melodic/share/nerian_stereo`.

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-02-18**:
Did you source your workspace first?
When you are at ~/catkin_ws, try to `source devel/setup.bash` and then `catkin_make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik importing msgs in Python would follow the pattern:

```
from pkg_name.msg import SomeMsg
```

In your case you'd probably have to adapt your `import` line to use that pattern, or spec `msg.StereoCameraInfo` in your `rospy.Subscriber(..)` line.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-18**:
Now it did work, yes. It was `from nerian_stereo.msg import StereoCameraInfo` . If you add it as answer I can accept.